# Power Apps, Patch and Lookup ID to update record

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to update my field "Status".

I am using the logic from here: [Create and Update Patch Formula for Power Apps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282979/create-and-update-patch-formula-for-power-apps)

```
 Patch('Questionnaire',
LookUp('Questionnaire',ID=Value(DataCardValue20.Text)),
{Status:"Submitted"});

SubmitForm(EditForm1_1);Refresh('Questionnaire')
```

but nothing changes when I  click my submit button.

DataCardValue20 is my ID field.
What could I do here to fix this?

[image]

Comment: If Patch and SubmitForm is on same data source, try using SubmitForm function first and then Patch function. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes that worked... not sure why...

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are using SubmitForm function  after Patch function.

SubmitForm is overriding the value you set using Patch function.

So, try using this:

```
SubmitForm(EditForm1_1);
Patch('Questionnaire',
LookUp('Questionnaire',ID=Value(DataCardValue20.Text)),
{Status:"Submitted"});

Refresh('Questionnaire')
```